# Dynamic array allocation during constructing object, invalid use of non-static variable

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

```
class Array {                                           

public:

    Array(unsigned h, unsigned l, std::initializer_list<double>);
    ....
private:
    unsigned length;
    double * array;
...
};

Array::Array(unsigned l, std::initializer_list<double> il) :
length(l)
{
    array(new (std::nothrow) array[l]);
    if (!array)
        throw OutOfMem();
    for (auto el = il.begin(), int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
            if (el === il.end())
                throw WrongDim();
            array[i] = *el;
            el++;
        }
    }
}
```

It's justthe draft of the original class which i have to do for my assignment. Compiling results in error:

invalid use of non-static data member 'length'
unsigned length;

Anyone got any clue how to fix this?

Comment: That's pretty confusing code you have there. You're missing `h` from the ctor definition, so probably the compiler doesn't parse it as a ctor, but something weird. Second, the initialisation of `array` should probably be in the mem-initializer-list as well, and you probably meant `new (std::nothrow) double[l]`.

Comment: When you post questions about error, please *always* include the complete error log in the question, and also mark out where in the source the errors are.

Comment: the full error log contains more than 6 pages, most of which as i can observe is the result of bad allocation. That's why i was asking about it. The problem is i don't know why even tough i always have to initialize those values i cannot use them to allocate dynamic array in a constructed object

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
int i=0;
for (auto &el : il)
    array[i++] = el;

if (i!=l) 
    throw WrongDim();
```

Comment: Please explain how this code helps the OP and further readers of this thread to solve the proble. You can find more about answering guidelines in the [help]: [answer]